# Remove/Disable selected options from a dropdown(Which is dynamically created) in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8, angular9

I have a dynamic dropdown with some fields.
[image]

- press + button will generate a new row.We can have any number of rows here.
- I need to Remove/Disable the previously selected dropdown values from here

I have stored selected items and my entire list like this.

```
SelectedFieldList =["ProductCode","Name"];
FieldList=["ProductCode","Name","Code","Image","Category", etc..]
```

I have tried to disable the selected Options using this code

```
 <select formControlName="FieldName">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let FieldItem of FieldList">
                          <option *ngIf="!SelectedFieldList.includes(FieldItem)"  [value]="FieldItem">{{FieldItem}}</option>
                          <option [disabled]="true" *ngIf="SelectedFieldList.includes(FieldItem)"  [value]="FieldItem">{{FieldItem}}</option>
                        </ng-container>
                      </select>
```

This is working fine inside the dropdown. But the issue is after disabling the previously selected item in the next button click. This is changing the already selected dropdown values. Means it's also disabling from the already selected dropdowns and showing the next related value.

In the above screenshot, I have selected the "Product number" .But after clicking + button it's disabled from the next dropdown successfully. but it's changed the value to "Product code" in the first dropdown(Product number is also there but it's a disabled format).
[image]

any solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you bind the condition to disabled input?

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let FieldItem of FieldList">
    <option [disabled]="SelectedFieldList.includes(FieldItem)"  [value]="FieldItem">{{FieldItem}}</option>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: @Ajas Aju did this solution work for you? I am having same requirement but this is not working.

Comment: Hi @Pinka , I have maintained an array for all selected items in the dropdown change event and wrote a condition on the select-options.

`<option [value]="FieldItem" *ngIf="SelectedSkunestFieldList.includes(FieldItem)" disabled style="background-color:dimgrey;color:white">{{FieldItem}}</option>
 <option [value]="FieldItem" *ngIf="!SelectedSkunestFieldList.includes(FieldItem)">{{FieldItem}}</option>`

please compare with my aforementioned example.

Comment: I am disabling and changing the colour if the `fieldItem` in the `SelectedSkunestFieldList` array.Otherwise it will list all fields normally.